# Difference between worker and service in the context of infrastructure primitives

Tags: amazon-web-services, service, celery, software-design, infrastructure

I am building infrastructure primitives to support workers and http services.

- workers are standalone
- http services have a web server and a load balancer

The way I understand it, a worker generally pull from an external resource to consume tasks while a service handles inbound requests and talks to upstream services.

Celery is an obvious worker and a web app is an obvious service. The lines can get blurry though and I'm not sure what the best approach is:

- Is the worker/service primitive a good idea?
- What if there's a service that consumes tasks like a worker but also handles some http requests to add tasks? Is this a worker or a service?
- What about services that don't go through nginx, does that mean a third "network" primitive with an NLB is the way to go?
- What about instances of a stateful service that a master service connects to? The master has to know the individual agent instances so we cannot
  hide them behind a LB. How would you go about representing that?

Answer (score 0):

- Is the worker/service primitive a good idea?

> IMO, the main difference between service and worker can be that workers should be  only designated to one task but service can perform multiple tasks. A service can 
>   utilize a worker or a chain of workers to process the user request.

- What if there's a service that consumes tasks like a worker but also handles some http requests to add tasks?

> Services can be of different forms like web service, FTP service, SNMP 
>   service or processing service. Writing the processing logic in service may not be  a good idea unless it is taking the form of a worker.

- What about services that don't go through nginx, does that mean a third "network" primitive with an NLB is the way to go?

> I believe you are assuming service to be only HTTP based but as I mentioned in the previous answer, services can be of different types. Yes you may write a TCP service for a particular protocol implementation that can be attached behind an NLB

- What about instances of a stateful service that a hub service connects to? The hub has to know the individual instances so we cannot hide them behind a LB.

> Not sure what you mean by hub here? But good practice for a scalable architecture is to use stateless servers/services behind. The session state should not be stored in the service memory but should be serialized to a data store like DynamoDB.

Comment: updated question. some services like a selenium hub require bidirectional access so I cannot put agent nodes behind a LB.

Answer (score 0):

One way to see the difference is to look at their names - workers do what their name says - they perform (typically) heavy tasks (work) - something you do not want your service to be bothered with, *especially* if it is a microservice. - For this particular reason, you will rarely see 32-core machines with hundred GBs of RAM running services, but you will very often see them running workers. Finally, they complement each other well. Services off-load heavy tasks to the workers. This aligns with the well-known UNIX philosophy "do one thing, and do it well".